# "Use of unassigned local variable" error with an Interface

Tags: c#, interface, null

I'm having trouble with some syntax. I'm not really familiar with interfaces so please excuse my ignorance.

VS2010 is giving me an error at... `application.Name = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;`

```
public static void AddApplication(string applicationName = null, string processImageFileName = null)
{
    INetFwAuthorizedApplications applications;
    INetFwAuthorizedApplication application;

    if(applicationName == null)
    {
        application.Name = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;/*set the name of the application */
    }
    else
    {
        application.Name = applicationName;/*set the name of the application */
    }

    if (processImageFileName == null)
    {
        application.ProcessImageFileName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location; /* set this property to the location of the executable file of the application*/
    }
    else
    {
        application.ProcessImageFileName = processImageFileName; /* set this property to the location of the executable file of the application*/
    }

    application.Enabled =  true; //enable it

    /*now add this application to AuthorizedApplications collection */
    Type NetFwMgrType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwMgr", false); 
    INetFwMgr mgr = (INetFwMgr)Activator.CreateInstance(NetFwMgrType); 
    applications = (INetFwAuthorizedApplications)mgr.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.AuthorizedApplications;
    applications.Add(application);
}
```

I can make that error go away by setting `application` to `null` but that causes a run-time null reference error.

Edit:

Here's where I'm adapting the code from. I hope it gives more context
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/securitytools/archive/2009/08/21/automating-windows-firewall-settings-with-c.aspx

Comment: The error says exactly what is wrong.  You declare a variable and never initialize it.

Comment: In the code you are referring to, `applications` is initialized to `(INetFwAuthorizedApplications)mgr.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.AuthorizedApplications;` Then that collection is looped through assigning each entry to `application`. You are not doing any of that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You never initialize

```
application
```

before using it here:

```
application.Name = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
```

The variable application is defined as:

```
INetFwAuthorizedApplication application
```

You need to assign an instance of a class that implements the interface `INetFwAuthorizedApplication`.

Somewhere there must be one (or probably more) classes in your project that look something like this:

```
public class SomeClass : INetFwAuthorizedApplication
{
    // ...
}

public class AnotherClass : INetFwAuthorizedApplication
{
    // ...
}
```

You need to determine what class you should use (SomeClass, AnotherClass) then assign an appropriate object, e.g. like this:

```
INetFwAuthorizedApplication application = new SomeClass();
```

Comment: I tried initializing it with a "new" but apparently I can't do that since it's an interface. How do I get around that?

Comment: You need to set it to an instance of an object that implements the interface.

Comment: I'm really sorry. Would you mind dumbing that down for me a bit?

Comment: @Kashif: It makes no sense to create an instance of an interface.  What would it do exactly?  You can declare a variable as an interface type, but you must create or obtain an instance of a concrete implementation to assign to it, i.e., `SomeInterface x = new SomeInterfaceImplementation();` or `SomeInterface x = GetSomeObject();`

Comment: I added some clarification to my answer.

Comment: @Kashif It appears that these interfaces deal with the windows firewall. Some googling lead to this blog: http://blog.csharphelper.com/2010/10/09/access-firewall-information-and-check-firewall-status-using-the-dynamic-keyword-in-c.aspx and this msdn page:http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.activator.aspx you need to use the Activator class to get an instance that implements the INetFwAuthorizedApplication - Activator.CreateInstance() seems to be a factory method that generates the instance you need.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces are used to describe what an object does, not what it is specifically.  To put into "real world" terms, an interface might be like:

`ISmallerThanABreadbox` with a `FitIntoBreadbox()` method.  I can't ask you to give me "the smaller than a breadbox" ... as that doesn't make any sense.  I can only ask you to give me something that "IS smaller than a breadbox".  You have to come up with your own object that makes sense to have the interface on it.  An apple is smaller than a breadbox, so if you have a breadbox that only holds items smaller than it, an apple is a good candidate for the `ISmallerThanABreadbox` interface.

Another example is `IGraspable` with a `Hold()` method and `FitsInPocket` bool property.  You can ask to be given something that IS graspable that may or may not fit in your pocket, but you can't ask for "the graspable".

Hope that helps...